# Cross domain exception

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, cross-domain

I uploaded my wordpress blog on url : http://blog.in

I am getting cross domain exception while calling following url

```
                $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "http://app.blog.in/getToken",
                          contentType: "text/html",
                              success: function(msg) {
                                            alert(msg);
                          }
                    });
```

Please suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading from a different subdomain, browser security doesn't allow that.
Unless you can move the data you're loading to the same domain (that's same subdomain as well), you should look into using [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/). Then you can load data from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a cross-domain error because you are crossing domains: `app.blog.in` and `blog.in`. You should serve the content from the same domain as where you post it.

Comment: Look at the evidence before you.