# jQuery JSON AJAX request fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1GBP=?USD",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function() {
        alert("success");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('fail');
    });
});​
```

I'm new to this so please can someone tell me why does this fail? 
In firebug I am getting '200 OK' for the request.

Comment: What is this part of your url .. =?USD

Comment: It's the search query ("is which amount of US Dollars")

Comment: It doesn't look like that api supports JSONP, or at least I couldn't guess at what the jsonp callback param was. Doesn't look like an api that was meant to be accessed by other applications outside the google network of sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make an ajax request to www.google.com unless the script from which the ajax request originates is loaded from www.google.com.  It's called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Browsers won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing to a "cross-domain" request exception.

Here is one of plenty related topic : [Cross domain exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932779/cross-domain-exception)